# Default to existing value in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Does anyone know if there's a way in terraform to default settings to that of an existing resource, and only set them when creating a new resource?

For example when I'm creating a new instance, I'll want to use the latest AMI, but for an existing instance (which should have all the latest patches, etc), there'd be no need to update the AMI.

Comment: Right - so after repeated searching leading to nothing, before asking the question, I think I might have found the answer shortly after in the form of terraform lifecycle hooks.

If so, I'll close this question ( with that answer ), after I've confirmed it.

Answer (score 3):

Every resource in terraform has a [lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle). You can configure the lifecycle to ignore certain changes to a resource.

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
  ami                    = "my_ami"
  instance_type          = ".."

  ..

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["ami"]
  }
}
```

If you want to update the ami of that existing resource later, you could then use the [taint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html) command.